# Pymunk Segment trouble?

Tags: python, physics, segment, pymunk

I'm using Pymunk 3.0.0 on a Raspberry Pi running Debian Wheezy 7.0.
When I try making a shape using the 'pymunk.Segment' function I end up with only the first line of the polygon.  The same happens in both the Flipper and BouncingBalls demos so I'm fairly sure it's not my code.

For instance...

```
    static_body = pymunk.Body()
    static_lines = [pymunk.Segment(static_body, (150, 100.0), (50.0, 550.0),3.0)
            ,pymunk.Segment(static_body, (450.0, 100.0), (550.0, 550.0), 3.0)
            ,pymunk.Segment(static_body, (50.0, 550.0), (300.0, 600.0), 3.0)
            ,pymunk.Segment(static_body, (300.0, 600.0), (550.0, 550.0), 3.0)
            ,pymunk.Segment(static_body, (300.0, 420.0), (400.0, 400.0), 3.0)
            ]  
    for line in static_lines:
        line.elasticity = 0.7
        line.group = 1
    space.add(static_lines)
```

...would only create the line from 150,100 to 50,550 and not the other 4.

And when I try to draw the lines using PyGame then first line is drawn okay but the rest are just a very short, thin line at the body's location.

As this happens in the examples I'm assuming it's a bug with Pymunk/Chipmunk/Linux but can't find anything on Google.

Any help much appreciated (noob btw)

Dave.

Comment: Can you try and run the tests and see if they pass? Go to the tools folder and do >>>python run_tests.py

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that the older versions of pymunk expect each new body or shape to be added as a different argument to `space.add()`.

So try changing `space.add(static_lines)` to `space.add(*static_lines)`.